# Ubuntu 23.10 DisplayLink driver issue after upgrade from 22.04

Tags: drivers, upgrade, 23.10, displaylink, docking

I've upgraded from Ubuntu 22.04 to 23.10 and the display links on my docking stations don't work anymore. I have a Dell D3100 and a D-link DUB-M810 and the issue is the same with both.

I reinstalled the driver from here: https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu
but didn't help.

I freshly installed Ubuntu 23.10 on another computer and after driver installation both docking station work well but on the system which was upgraded from older version I cannot make it work.

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: DisplayLink drivers are available in the kernel itself.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr what worked for me

Uninstall the DisplayLink driver:

```
sudo displaylink-installer uninstall
```

Update the graphics drivers:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install
```

Reinstall the DisplayLink driver

```
sudo ./displaylink-driver-5.8.0-63.33.run
```

Reboot.

## Background

Ran into this issue myself on a Lenovo P15V with Quadro P620 graphics card running DisplayLink over USB-C to a [Lenovo ThinkPad Hybrid USB-C with USB-A Dock DUD9011D1](https://www.lenovo.com/ca/en/p/accessories-and-software/docking/docking_usb-docks-(universal-cable-docks)/40af0135us). I had Ubuntu 22.04 running on the laptop after several upgrades - probably started on 21.04.

I did default upgrade with installer to get to 23.10, which went without any noticed errors, but then when I rebooted, I could no longer see the option for external displays in Settings > Screen Display.

However, the USB keyboard, mouse, and ethernet all worked, so I suspected an issue higher up in the communication stack, likely in the graphics/display handling.

I found the [Arch Linux DisplayLink wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/DisplayLink) and when I ran

```
sudo dmesg
```

I got a repeating bank of these errors alternating:

```
evdi: disagrees about version of symbol sme_me_mask
evdi: Unknown symbol sme_me_mask (err -22)
```

Found a similar issue happening on [this gitub issue](https://github.com/DisplayLink/evdi/issues/135).

## What I did to fix it

"Disagrees about version of symbol" suggested to me that there was an issue with a dynamically linked library with symbol "sme_me_mask" - maybe a collision or dependency issue? I figured something broke in the upgrade and that uninstalling & reinstalling the DisplayLink & graphics drivers could help.

First, I removed the DisplayLink driver using its [official uninstall script](https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/683699-how-to-uninstall-displaylink-ubuntu-software):

```
sudo displaylink-installer uninstall
```

Then, I updated the Nvidia graphics drivers from the [Ubuntu instructions on updating Nvidia drivers](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/nvidia-drivers-installation):

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install
```

I then reinstalled the [DisplayLink driver from Synaptics](https://www.synaptics.com/products/displaylink-graphics/downloads/ubuntu):

```
sudo ./displaylink-driver-5.8.0-63.33.run
```

One reboot later and the displays were working again.

Hope that helps!